# Android app widget with dynamic text rows

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

How to implement such an app widget?

[image: widget screenshot]

User can select how many data rows to show through the widget configuration. The problem is that on different devices TextViews have different sizes and the widget itself has different sizes too. Even when device orientation changes the widget change its size too. So I don't know how to determine how many text rows fit the widget in current conditions and how to put a text in a bottom of the widget.